# Error or Breaking changes in Nest Class-validator@0.13.2

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying update `class-validator` from 0.13.2 to 0.14.0 because the v.0.13.2 have high risk vulnerabilities but when Update the Package `Class-validator` the console give me this error and I can not put others commands like npm install, etc...

```
PS C:\Users\rabur\OneDrive\Desktop\life-back\application> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @nestjs/mapped-types@1.2.0
npm ERR! Found: class-validator@0.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/class-validator
npm ERR!   class-validator@"^0.14.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional class-validator@"*" from @nestjs/common@9.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nestjs/common
npm ERR!     @nestjs/common@"^9.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @nestjs/common@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from @nestjs/config@2.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@nestjs/config
npm ERR!       @nestjs/config@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     7 more (@nestjs/core, @nestjs/jwt, @nestjs/mapped-types, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional class-validator@"^0.11.1 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0" from @nestjs/mapped-types@1.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/mapped-types
npm ERR!   @nestjs/mapped-types@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: class-validator@0.13.2
npm ERR! node_modules/class-validator
npm ERR!   peerOptional class-validator@"^0.11.1 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0" from @nestjs/mapped-types@1.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nestjs/mapped-types
npm ERR!     @nestjs/mapped-types@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\rabur\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rabur\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-16T20_28_35_415Z-debug-0.log
```

My package.json here

```
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^1.2.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "helmet": "^6.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.5",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^4.0.7",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "stripe": "^11.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "29.3.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

I'm trying update all packages from my package.json to latest version, but only this one have conflicts.

The alternative is come back to v0.13.2 but It have high risk vulnerabilities

Comment: [By the way, you're probably not actually at risk](https://github.com/nestjs/mapped-types/pull/949#issuecomment-1383056801)

Comment: Thanks Jay for your time to answer. I'm calm now

Answer (score 0):

Open `package-lock.json` and find a line `class-validator": "^0.11.1 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0"` for block `@nestjs/mapped-types`.

Change it to `"class-validator": "0.14.0"`

[image: code]